# "Edit Page" vs "Page > Edit"?

Tags: 2010

What is the difference between my editing a page via the two methods:

- Selecting "Edit Page" from the Site Actions menu
- Selecting "Edit" from the "Page" tab of the ribbon

Are they simply two ways to identical operations? Does either have side effects the other does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are identical.

You use *"Edit Page" from the Site Actions menu"* when the page resides on a Publishing site, and you use *"Edit" from the "Page" tab of the ribbon* when the page resides on a non-publishing site or is already in the **Checked out** state.

Comment: That's a lot of words speaking to differences to actually be the same. Close but !=